# How can i parse through xml data from consumed web service Android?

Tags: android, xml, service, xml-parsing

I have a web service, `.asmx` that when consumed gives a response in the form:

```
<lData>
    <name>...</name>
    <posx>..</posx>
    <posy>...</posy>
</lData>
```

I use `Ksoap2` to consume the web service in `Android`, and I see the response as a `string`:

```
anyType {
    lData = anyType{
        name=....;
        posx=....;
        posy=....
    ;}
;}
```

So, I get the right data from my web service, but i don't know how to parse it correctly. 
I want to find a way to iterate through the different nodes.

I have tried to use a `SAXParser`, but can't seem to understand what I should use instead of the `url`. In the tutotirals I have followed the link to a xml-file on a `url`, but my `url` is only part "finished" since i need to consume the web service first.

```
MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

Is this above something I should use, but have another openStream?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAXParser wants an InputStream to parse.  I think you are saying that you have a string of xml you want to parse?  To do so, you need to turn your String into an input stream:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Hi!Well, the web service sends data in xml-form, so that if i take the response.toString() I can read it in a TextView. So I have seen that it is working, the web service connection that is. But now i want to take this information and use it in a listview later on. I tried to use this above, but in order to do this I first have to convert my envelope.getResponse(); to a string. I am thinking that maybe there is a way without that step? I didn't get it to work, my app now has this "sorry shut down" error, so I have to go over the code carefully to find what is wrong.

Comment: After the InputStream, should I use  InputSource is2 = new InputSource(is);
      xr.parse(is2); ? Thanks again!

Comment: You implied you had it as a string already, which is why I suggested that.  I agree that in general, converting it to a string should not be necessary.  What object type do you have?  As to the 2nd question, SAXParser has a parse method that takes an InputStream, so you do not need to turn it into an InputSource.

Comment: This is my object:  response = envelope.getResponse(); SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);

// xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format the questions in these comment boxes. Instead of the inputSource(sourceURL.openStream), what do you suggest I should use?

Comment: xr.parse(inputStream);  You didn't really answer the question though, what type is the object response?

Comment: I am a beginner, so I don't really know what type the object response is, I just declare it Object response = null; and then use it to put the envelope response in. Maybe that is not the way to do it? I am using SoapObject to communicate with the web service? Is there a certain object type that would be best to use? If you know of a good tutorial, please tell me so I can go read up. I have found many, but none that has helped me figure this out!

Comment: Ok, until you figure out what the envelope.getResponse() is giving you, I can't tell you what you need to do to it to turn it into an inputStream.  You could debug the app, put a breakpoint right after envelope.getResponse() and examine what it gives you.

Comment: What I ended up doing was using the Object data1 = (SoapObject) response.getProperty (0); method and then I got the root element, and then getProperty of the data1 object to get the elements below. It is probably not the best way to do it cause I can't parse it with a for loop and "specify" element, but at least it works for now.